# 'act up' - how did it get its meaning and what does "up" mean?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, phrasal-verbs

Act up:

1. If a machine or part of the body acts up, it does not work as it should
2. To make somebody annoyed by behaving badly, trying to get attention, etc.

> The kids started acting up.
>   The car's acting up again.

I would like to know how *act up* came to get its meaning. Also, what is the meaning of the word *up* and how is it being used? Is it compared with *down* in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phrasal verbs particle *up*  can have various meanings and not necessarily  express the opposite of *down*.

*Up* can express the happening, the **emergence** of something:

> What's up ?
>   The kids started acting up.
>   I can't go on holiday, something unexpected's come up.
>   I'll pop up and see you on my way home.

In none of these cases could we obtain the opposite meaning of the phrase by replacing *up* with *down* as we can in *get up/get down*.
Or we'd have to change the verb altogether. For example we could say:

> The kids are now calming down.

*Up* can mean other things as well. Apart from the opposite of *down*, one of its usual meaning is to express **completion**, such as in:

> The car's paid up. I've no more debts.
>   Come on eat it up, finish what's in your plate.

It can express **improving** something :

> Cheer up!
>   This text isn't very good, you should polish it up a little.